# How to change $(MAKE) for all sub-makes?

Tags: makefile

I would like to redefine `MAKE := $(MAKE) --warn-undefined-variables` and this works but only for the first level.

When the first level invokes another makes, this definition is not kept.

How could I do this?

Comment: At the top level, do you make one call to `MAKE`, or several? Do the sub-Make processes use the same makefile as the top one?

Comment: And are you sure you want to redefine `MAKE`, and not just pass an option?

Answer (score 0):

Variable values of the top-level make can be passed to the sub-make through the environment by explicit request.

These variables are defined in the sub-make as defaults, but they do not override variables defined in the makefile used by the sub-make unless you use the ‘-e’ switch

To pass down, or export, a variable, make adds the variable and its value to the environment for running each line of the recipe. The sub-make, in turn, uses the environment to initialize its table of variable values.
As a convenience, you can define a variable and export it at the same time by doing:

```
export variable := value
```

or

```
variable := value
export variable
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html